# Show elements of a specific class Javascript(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, show

```
<div id=klik>KLIK   </div>
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="line">1</div>
        <div class="line">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="line">3</div>
    <div class="line">4</div>
</div>
```

This is the Html. I use Javscript to hide the whole list first. Then I would like to make a onclick function to show just the first two elements, the two in div list wrapper. This the code i have written.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".list").hide();

$("#klik").click(function(){
$(".list-wrapper").show();

});
});
```

The problem it never shows the elements.

Comment: What you're hiding and showing are different elements. This is probably your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to show an element that is still wrapped inside a hidden parent element. In case you hide and show the same selection it is working just fine. You could do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".list").hide();

   $("#klik").click(function(){
      $(".list").show().children().not('.list-wrapper').hide(); //show .list, then hide everything that is not inside .list-wrapper
   });

});​
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UgcZ2/)**

**EDIT:**
And fix your HTML markup (missing quotes `""` ) `<div id=klik>KLIK</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding the parent element of what you are trying to show.  `show` will only display the elements you called it on, it won't cascade up the DOM tree.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".list").hide();
    $("#klik").click(function(){
         $(".list").show(); //Show .list elements instead

    });
});
```